# How to override a static property of a parent object and let the parent object access the new value in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, static, properties, overriding

This is what I have: All objects that can be persisted on the database extend the DatabaseObject abstract class, which has all the logic code to actually watch for attribute changes and run the databas queries.

I'm using two static variables to define object-specific details. I define them generically in the base class, and then supposedly I overwrite them in the actual database objects.

The problem is: When the code in the parent class is actually executed, it uses the old parent value instead of the current object value.

Here's the code for the base class:

```
abstract class DatabaseObject {

    public $id;

    private static $databaseTable = NULL;
    private static $databaseFields = array();

    private $data = array();
    private $changedFields = array();

    public function IDatabaseObject($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->data = Database::GetSingle(self::$databaseTable, $id);

    Utils::copyToObject($this, $this->data, self::$databaseFields);
    }

    public static function Load($id) {
    return new self($userID);
    }

    public static function Create($data) {

    $id = Database::Insert(self::$databaseTable, $data);

    return new self($id);
    }

    public function Save() {
    $data = Utils::copyFromObject($this, $this->changedFields);

    Database::Update(self::$databaseTable, $data, $this->id);

    }

    public function __constructor() {
    // We do this to allow __get and __set to be called on public vars
    foreach(self::$databaseFields as $field) {
        unset($this->$field);
    }
    }

    public function __get($variableName) {
    return $this->$variableName;
    }

    public function __set($variableName, $variableValue) {
    // We only want to update what has been changed
    if(!in_array($variableName, $this->changedFields) && in_array($variableName, self::$databaseFields)) {
        array_push($this->changedFields, $variableName);
    }

    $this->$variableName = $variableValue;
    }
}
```

And here's the code for one of the objects extending the base class above:

```
class Client extends DatabaseObject {

    public static $databaseTable = "clients";
    public static $databaseFields = array("name","contactName","primaryUserID","email","is_active","rg","cpf","cnpj","ie","addrType","addrName","addrNumber","addrComplement","addrPostalCode","addrNeighborhood","addrCity","addrState","addrCountry","phoneLandline","phoneFax","phoneMobile");

    public $name;
    public $contactName;

    public $primaryUserID;
    public $email;

    public $is_active;

    public $rg;
    public $cpf;
    public $cnpj;
    public $ie;

    public $addrType;
    public $addrName;
    public $addrNumber;
    public $addrComplement;
    public $addrPostalCode;
    public $addrNeighborhood;
    public $addrCity;
    public $addrState;
    public $addrCountry;

    public $phoneLandline;
    public $phoneFax;
    public $phoneMobile;

    public static function Load($id) {
 return new Client($id);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there another way I can achieve the same result?

A brief addendum: I declare the attributes in the class body mainly to let it be seen by the NetBeans' auto-complete feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class inheritance in PHP 5.2: Overriding static variable in extension class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017777/class-inheritance-in-php-5-2-overriding-static-variable-in-extension-class)

Comment: This is a legit question in php, which has a pretty confusing implementation, but the question could really be narrowed down to make it more generic and accessible for other people to benefit from.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You are looking for [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

So you need to use:

```
static::$databaseTable
```

instead of

```
self::$databaseTable
```

This feature is available as of PHP 5.3. Simulating this in PHP 5.2 is very hard, because of two reasons: `get_called_class` is available only since PHP 5.3, too. Therefore it must be simulated, too, using `debug_backtrace`. The second problem is, that if you have the called class, you still may not use `$calledClass::$property` because this is a PHP 5.3 feature, too. Here you need to use `eval` or `Reflection`. So I do hope that you have PHP 5.3 ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade my PHP version. The server is running Plesk 9.5, which only supports up to 5.2.13; I fear manually upgrading it could break certain applciations.

I will see if I can devise an alternative way to do the same task.

Comment: The best way involves passing the class as a first parameter to any method which needs to access these properties.  That way, you can search that class directly for an override.  If not found, you can go up the parent ladder until you find the field.