# Static variable assignment in descendent bubbles up to parent?

Tags: php, static, aop, class-hierarchy

I've run into a problem and I'm not sure if this is just normal behaviour or if I wrote something wrong. I have a method in my base class that applies a global filter to a given class by way of creating a proxy for all new instances of that particular class. The way I planned to go about it is as follows:

1. Attach `static $global_filter` (the proxy) to the class I want to be filtered, which extends the base class `object`
2. Via my loading mechanism, return the proxy instead of the actual class upon new instantiations (which will mask method calls and apply filters accordingly)

However, I am getting stuck in *step 1* and it seems that when I try to assign `static $global_filter` to the descendent class I want filtered, my base class `object` also gets the same assignment, which breaks everything else that extends from it.

Please see below for relevant code:

```
class object {

    public static $global_filter;

    public function _filterGlobal($class, $method, $callback) {
        if ( !is_object($class::$global_filter) ) {
            $class::$global_filter = new filterable(null);
            # Replace the object being called with the new proxy.
        }
        var_dump($class);
        var_dump($class::$global_filter); // `filterable`
        var_dump(\core\blueprint\object::$global_filter); // Returns same as line above
        die();
        return $class::$global_filter->_add($method, $callback);
    }

}
```

Both `$class::$global_filter` and `\core\blueprint\object::$global_filter` (the base class) are returning same instance. Whereas I expected **`object::$global_filter` to be null**.

I'm not using late static binding in order to preserve consistency (both single-object filters and global filters are called much in the same way non-statically).

[This question seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017777/class-inheritance-in-php-5-2-overriding-static-variable-in-extension-class)

Any help will be much appreciated :)

#### Edit, full example

This would be a concrete class, which extends `model` which extends `object`

```
<?php
use core\blueprint\model;
class modelMock extends model {
    protected $schema = array();
    public function method($test) {
        return $test;
    }
}
```

This would be another object (e.g a controller), which extends `object` aswell. It applies a filter to all new instances of `model`

```
<?php
use core\blueprint\object;
class objectMock extends object {

    public function applyFilters() {
        $this->_filterGlobal('core\blueprint\model', 'method', function($self, $chain) {
            $chain->params[0] = 'new param'; // adjust the paramters
            return $chain->next();
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. I'm using something similar. Can we see a concrete class?

Comment: @iRaS piecing something together now

Comment: @iRaS just added an example to the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for you help, I spent some time on it this morning and managed to solve my problem. It's a bit of a workaround but here's how it goes:

```
public function _filterGlobal($class, $method, $callback) {
    if ( !is_object($class::$global_filter[$class]) ) {
        $class::$global_filter[$class] = new filterable(null);
        # Replace the object being called with the new proxy.
    }
    return $class::$global_filter[$class]->_add($method, $callback);
}
```

So basically in order to get unique static variables working in child classes without having to explicitly define them, you can use an array that stores the child's class name as a key and then access these variables via a getter.

Answer (score 1):

> when I try to assign static $global_filter to the descendent class I want filtered, my base class object also gets the same assignment

Yes, indeed this happens. A static property in essence is a global variable, constrained within the class's namespace. Running into problems with global variables is often an indication you're not using the best solution.

To solve your problem, you could make the filter a (non-static) property:

```
$class->$filter = new Whatever();
```

But as always, there's more roads that lead to Rome, and I would advise you to look for alterative ways to do it.

Comment: Thats not a solution for him. He wants all objects to get filtered by this filter and also already instantiated objects.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that static properties are constrained within the class' namespace. However iras is right, I need something that applies the filter to all new objects of the same class (although not necessarily already instantiated objects)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a help for you:

```
class a {
   public static $type;

   public static function setType($class, $newType) {
      $class::$type = $newType;
      var_dump($class::$type);
   }
}
class b {
   public static $type = 'myType';
}

var_dump(b::$type);
a::setType('b', 'yourType');
var_dump(a::$type);
```

May be you have not defined the static property to the concrete class.

Comment: Thanks for that, but most of my objects need to be filterable so I can't rely afford to add a static property to each individual object, and can't trust others to do so when writing new objects.

Comment: sorry, no good news i guess. without the declaration of the static property in the concrete class i see no way for your request. it looks like redeclaring but it's a new static property for each class otherwise it's a static property of the parent class.

Comment: Ahhh okay I see, alright thanks for your help :) I'll look into it some more today